# Mover elemento de uma div para outra sem mudar o estado

Tags: javascript

**Como mover o conteúdo de uma `div` para outra `div` e manter o estado dos elementos?**

**Exemplo:** mover um `input` de uma `div` para outra, sem criar um novo `input` e deletar o antigo, como acontece no código abaixo, mantendo assim o valor digitado no `input.

Este código é só um exemplo básico do que estou tentando fazer, não tem nada "caprichado".

> Eu poderia pegar o valor do `input` antigo e coloca-lo no novo `input`, mas estou usando o `input` como exemplo poderia ser qualquer outro elemento.

```js
window.onload = function(){document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value="Valor do input";};
function mover(){
  origem = document.getElementById("origem");
  destino = document.getElementById("destino");
  
  destino.innerHTML = origem.innerHTML;
  origem.innerHTML="";
}
```

```html
<div style="background:green" id="origem"><input id="input"></div>
<div style="background:red" id="destino"></div>
<button onclick="mover()">MOVER</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método `children` para obter todos os elementos filhos do elemento pai e o `appendChild` para adicionar os elementos no novo elemento pai.

```
function mover() {
    origem = document.getElementById("origem");
    destino = document.getElementById("destino");

    filhos = Array.prototype.slice.call(origem.children); //Convertendo HTMLCollection para Array
    filhos.forEach(function(element, index) {
        destino.appendChild(element);
    });
}
```

> O método [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Summary) remove o nó do elemento pai atual antes de adicioná-lo ao novo elemento pai.

Comment: Como eu disse na pergunta `Como mover o conteúdo de uma div`, pode haver mais de um elemento, da forma que você apresentou eu teria q selecionar cada elemento individualmente, não seria viavel.
Por isso usei `innerHTML` para pegar tudo dentro da `div`

Comment: @MarkVaaz, atualizei a resposta.